# Concatenating a vector of column names in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking to add a column to a `data.table` which is a concatenation of several other columns, the names of which I've stored in a vector `cols`. Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682545/1840471 I tried `do.call` + `paste` but couldn't get it working. Here's what I've tried:

```
# Using mtcars as example, e.g. first record should be "110 21 6"
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
cols <- c("hp", "mpg", "cyl")
# Works old-fashioned way
dt[, slice.verify := paste(hp, mpg, cyl)]
# Raw do.call+paste fails with message:
# Error in do.call(paste, cols): second argument must be a list
dt[, slice := do.call(paste, cols)]
# Making cols a list makes the column "hpmpgcyl" for each row
dt[, slice := do.call(paste, as.list(cols))]
# Applying get fails with message:
# Error in (function (x) : unused arguments ("mpg", "cyl")
dt[, slice := do.call(function(x) paste(get(x)), as.list(cols))]
```

Help appreciated - thanks.

*Similar questions:*

- [Concatenate columns and add them to beginning of Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682462/concatenate-columns-and-add-them-to-beginning-of-data-frame) (operates on `data.frames` using `cbind` and `do.call` - this was very slow on my `data.table`)
- [R - concatenate row-wise across specific columns of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308933/r-concatenate-row-wise-across-specific-columns-of-dataframe) (doesn't deal with columns as names or large number of columns)
- [Accessing columns in data.table using a character vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007979/accessing-columns-in-data-table-using-a-character-vector-of-column-names) (considers aggregation using column names)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of elements in 'cols' as a `list`

```
dt[, slice := do.call(paste, mget(cols))]
head(dt, 2)
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    slice
#1:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 110 21 6
#2:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 110 21 6
```

---

Or another option is to specify the 'cols' in `.SDcols` and `paste` the `.SD`

```
dt[, slice:= do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = cols]
head(dt, 2)
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    slice
#1:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 110 21 6
#2:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 110 21 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen `mget` before and don't see it in the references. How does this work differently from `get`?

Comment: @MaxGhenis @MaxGhenis  It is similar to using `get` in a loop (for vectors that have length >1) `dt[, slice := do.call(paste, lapply(cols,  function(x) get(x)))]`

Comment: `.SDcols` is the idiomatic way- just to make it clear. `mget`/`get` could get slow in different situations.

Answer (score 1):

Came across a possibly more simple solution using apply as follows:

```
df[, "combned_column"] <- apply(df[, cols], 1, paste0, collapse = "")
```

May not work for data.tables, but it did what I needed and possibly what was needed here.